# Wordcloud showing colour based on continuous metadata in R

Tags: r, colors, text-mining, word-cloud, color-palette

I'm creating a wordcloud in which the size of the words is based on frequency, but i want the colour of the words to be mapped to a third variable (stress, which is the amount of stress associated with each word, a numerical or continuous variable).

I tried the following, which gave me only two different colours (yellow and purple) while i want something more smooth. I would like some color range like a palette that goes from green to red for example.

```
df = data.frame(word = c("calling", "meeting", "conference", "contract", "negotiation", "email"),
n = c(20, 12, 4, 8, 10, 43),
stress = c(23, 30, 15, 40, 35, 15))
df = tbl_df(df) 
wordcloud(words = df$word, freq = df$n, col = df$stress)
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this continous metadata and get some smoothly changing colour for the words when stress goes up? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this? `wordcloud(words = df$word, freq = df$n, col = brewer.pal(9,"BuGn"))`

Comment: Use RColorBrewer with brew <- brewer.pal(12, "Paired")

Comment: @jazzurro. But then the colour intensity/type is not mapped to the variable stress, is it?

Comment: Something like this then? `df %>% arrange(stress) -> foo ; wordcloud(words = foo$word, freq = foo$stress, scale = c(4, 0.5), col = brewer.pal(6,"YlOrRd"), ordered.colors = T)`. I am creating a prototype. So you probably need to do more. The idea is that you set up font size with `scale`. Then, You use `stress` in `freq`. I rearranged the order of your data by `stress`. Contact has the highest value, and it receives the darkest color. You may want to create some groups for `stress` as a new variable and think how you could assign colors.

Comment: `wordcloud(words = foo$word, freq = foo$n, scale = c(8, 1), col = brewer.pal(6,"YlOrRd"), ordered.colors = T)` This seems to do your favor.

Comment: I get it, i understand, cool.

Comment: I finally got time to think about your question properly. Have a look of the solution below. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a potential solution. You want to use the `wordcloud2` package for your task. Then, you can solve your issue, I suppose. Since I do not know your real data, I created a sample data to demonstrate a prototype.

If you have many words, I am not sure if adding colors with a continuous variable (stress) is a good idea. One thing you could do is to create a new group variable using `cut()`. In this way, you can reduce the numbers of colors you would use in your graphics. Here, I created a new column called `color` with five colors from the viridis package.

When you use `wordcloud2()`, you have only two things to supply. One is data and the other is color. Font size reflects frequency of the words without specifying it.

```
mydf = data.frame(word = c("calling", "meeting", "conference", "contract", "negotiation",
                           "email", "friends", "chat", "text", "deal",
                           "business", "promotion", "discount", "users", "family"),
                  n = c(20, 12, 4, 8, 10, 43, 33, 5, 47, 28, 12, 9, 50, 31, 22),
                  stress = c(23, 30, 15, 40, 35, 15, 30, 18, 10, 5, 29, 38, 45, 8, 3))


          word  n stress
1      calling 20     23
2      meeting 12     30
3   conference  4     15
4     contract  8     40
5  negotiation 10     35
6        email 43     15
7      friends 33     30
8         chat  5     18
9         text 47     10
10        deal 28      5
11    business 12     29
12   promotion  9     38
13    discount 50     45
14       users 31      8
15      family 22      3

library(dplyr)
library(wordcloud2)
library(viridis)

mutate(mydf, color = cut(stress, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, Inf),
             labels = c("#FDE725FF", "#73D055FF", "#1F968BFF",
                        "#2D708EFF", "#481567FF"),
             include.lowest = TRUE)) -> temp

wordcloud2(data = temp, color = temp$color)
```

[image]

Comment: it fully worked, i used a more continous colour palette, it looks just beautiful!

Comment: @BenjaminTelkamp I am glad that this idea worked for you!

Answer (score 3):

Or something a bit more automatic instead of specifying the exact threshold values and colors:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud2)

mydf = data.frame(word = c("calling", "meeting", "conference", "contract", "negotiation",
                       "email", "friends", "chat", "text", "deal",
                       "business", "promotion", "discount", "users", "family"),
              n = c(20, 12, 4, 8, 10, 43, 33, 5, 47, 28, 12, 9, 50, 31, 22),
              stress = c(23, 30, 15, 40, 35, 15, 30, 18, 10, 5, 29, 38, 45, 8, 3))

color_range_number <- length(unique(mydf$stress))
color <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues")[3:7])(color_range_number)[factor(mydf$stress)]

wordcloud2(mydf, color=color)
```

So that the size is determined by 'n', and the shade of color determined by 'stress'.
[image]

[3:7] is for adjusting the color scale range. 1 is the lightest and 9 is the darkest.

You may check the other color palette options by:

```
display.brewer.all()
```