# wordcloud2 does not display numbered colors

Tags: r, colors, wordcloud2

When I use numbered colors in wordcloud2, nothing is displayed.

```
library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(demoFreq,color='blue1')
```

Color names without numbers are ok. E.g. color='blue'

What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894416/wordcloud-showing-colour-based-on-continous-metadata-in-r). I think this will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the word cloud is being rendered in HTML,  you need to use html colors. `blue1` is an R color, not HTML,  so you need to convert it to a hex value color. the R function `col2rgb` will give an RGB triple, but that will not work with HTML. You need to convert the triple to a hex value. You can do that using `rgb`.  However, `rgb` expects 3 columns,  not a column of 3 values,  so use `t` to transpose the RGB values.

```
rgb(t(col2rgb("blue1")),  maxColorValue = 255)
[1] "#0000FF"
```

Now you can successfully call `wordcloud2`

```
wordcloud2(demoFreq, color=rgb(t(col2rgb("blue1")), maxColorValue = 255))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably [HTML color codes](https://html-color-codes.info/) are meant by "numbered colors", e.g.

```
wordcloud2(demoFreq, color= "#0080CC")
```

When `"blue1"` is not defined anywhere `wordcloud2()` has no color to use. But you could define one yourself.

```
library(wordcloud2)
blue1 <- "#0080CC"
wordcloud2(demoFreq, color= blue1)
```

Note that there are no quotes `""` in this case.

There are more color *names* available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp). The package itself defines `'random-dark'` and `'random-light'` in addition.

***Edit:*** According to @GW5's comment use following code to obtain exactly the desired `"blue1"`as a workaround:

```
blue1 <- colors()[27]
wordcloud2(demoFreq, color= blue1)
```

Comment: It is not true that "blue1" is not defined anywhere.  Try `colors()[27]` and also `col2rgb("blue1")`

Comment: Probably an issue of `wordcloud2`.